# Compilation on C, function error?

Tags: c, function, matrix, compilation

I started studying computer science a few months ago so this question may be a bit stupid, but I'd appreciate if someone could help me.
So my teacher asked us to make our version of a game called Bejeweled, I think I did ok so far but I started having this problem where I get the following error message :   **[Linker error] undefined reference to `change_position'**. For some reason the function change_position isn't letting my code compile, and I really can't understand why. In the following code the function has a "//" on the main function and it works fine, but without the // it gets that message. Can anyone explain me how to make it work? It would be even better if someone explained why it isn't working too. Thanks a lot and sorry for any english mistake.
Thanks a lot, I fixed the mistake I was making and now it works properly. You guys are awesome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void create_matrix (int matriz[8][8], int i, int j)
{
srand (time (NULL));
for (i=0;i<8;i++)
{
for (j=0;j<8;j++)
{
matriz[i][j]=rand()%7+1;
}
}
}
//___________________________________________________
void check_matrix(int matriz[8][8], int i, int j)
{
     for (i=0;i<8;i++)
         {
             for (j=0;j<8;j++)
           {    
               while (matriz[i][j] == matriz[i+1][j] && matriz[i+1][j] == matriz [i+2][j] || matriz [i][j] == matriz [i][j+1] && matriz [i][j+2])
               {
               matriz[i][j]=rand()%7+1;
               }
           }
     }
}
//___________________________________________________
void print_matrix (int matriz[8][8], int i, int j)
{
for (i = 0; i < 8 ; i++)
{
for (j=0;j<8;j++)
{
printf("%d ", matriz[i][j]);
}
printf ("\n");
}
}
//___________________________________________________
void change_position(int matriz[8][8], int i, int j)
{
printf ("Select the line. ");
scanf ("%d", &i);
printf ("Select the column. ");
scanf ("%d", &j);
}
//___________________________________________________
int main()
{
int matriz[8][8], i=0, j=0;
create_matrix (matriz, i, j);
check_matrix (matriz, i, j);
print_matrix (matriz, i, j);
change_position (matriz, i, j);
printf ("\n");
system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Linker errors aren't compiler errors.  You have a missing brace in `print_matrix` and an extra one after `change_position`.  If you indented your code better you'd see it immediately.

Comment: Please. Please. PLEASE, indent your code properly.

Comment: Standard advices: Try to indent properly your source file `bejeweled.c` (on Linux, you can use the command `indent bejeweled.c` for that). You'll find out that `print_matrix` is missing an ending brace. Then compile with all warnings (with `gcc -Wall -g bejeweled.c -o bejeweled`). Improve the code till no warnings are obtained. Then debug your program (e.g. with `gdb bejeweled`).

Comment: @cnicutar, he mentions that in his question.  Uncommenting the call site in `main` causes his link error.

Comment: @CarlNorum Oh, sorry. I forgot to uncomment it, that's right.

Comment: Is there a way to make gcc warn about nested functions like this?  They're almost never intended, and have been the source of several questions I've answered here over the last few days. Edit:  Hmm, my gcc has them disabled by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like print_matrix just above change_position is missing one more closing brace

Comment: .. and there's an extra close brace after `change_position`, too, which is why it compiles.  GCC nested functions, barf!

Comment: I didn't see that, nicer catch! :P

Answer (score 2):

Function `print_matrix` seems to have an error: You open three brackets but you close only two of them.